# Polynomial restricts to zero on a hyperplane implies divisibility

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

$F$ is a finite field and $p \in F[x_1, x_2, \ldots ,x_n]$ is a polynomial

If $p$ restricts to $0$ on a hyperplane $q = a_0 + a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n = 0$ in $F^n$ then does it follow that $q$ divides $p$?

By 'restricts to $0$' I mean if we parameterise $q$ by $n-1$ paramteters $t_i$ and compute the restriction of $p$ to $q$ (i.e. a polynomial in $F[t_1, \ldots, t_{n-1}]$ where $t_i$ are our parameters) this restriction is the *zero polynomial*.

Comment: What does "being a polynomial on $\,\Bbb F^n\,$" mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I meant that it is a polynomial with $n$ variables and coefficient in $F$

Comment: Please edit your question, as then you meant $\,p\in\Bbb F[X_1,...,X_n]\,$

Comment: I edited it, hope it makes sense now =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $n > 1$.

Consider the polynomial $p(x_1, \dots, x_n) = x_1^2 - x_{1}$ over the field $F = \mathbf{F}_{2}$. (So I might have written $-1 = 1$.)

Clearly $p$ evaluates to zero on *any element* of $F^{n}$. But $p$ is not divisible by, say, $q = x_2$.

---

The above was a solution to the problem as I understood it by reading a previous version, assuming that $p$ evaluates to zero on the hyperplane.

In the current formulation, I believe the answer to be positive.

Suppose WLOG $a_{n} \ne 0$, and do a change of variables so that the hyperplane is $q = x_{n} = 0$. (And the hyperplane is parametrized by $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$ in the obvious way.)

Now consider $p$ as a polynomial $p' \in K[x_{n}]$ in the variable $x_n$, with coefficients in $K = F[x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}]$.

If I understand correctly the assumption, this says that $p'(0) = 0$, that is, $p'$ has no constant term when regarded as a polynomial in $K[x_{n}]$, that is, it is a multiple of $q = x_{n}$, as required.

Comment: The hyperplane $q=x_2$ is parametrised by $(0,0) + t(1,0)$ so the restriction to $q$ is $p((0,0) + t(1,0)) = t^2 - t \neq 0$ i.e. is not the _zero polynomial_. I don't know if there is a better term for what I mean by "restricts to $0$" in the question?

Comment: I added to my question to explain what I meant by restricts to $0$

Comment: @DonAntonio, OP means zero as a polynomial, not just as a function.

Comment: @user65496, please check my edited answer and let me know whether it is ok.

Comment: @Andreas Yes this resolves my question, thank you for taking the time! I'm sorry for the confusing question, I did not think it was difficult but I'm not very familiar with the language